# C# - Sequentially add missing/unequal values from list 'A' into list 'B' whilst incrementing or maintaing the counter value

Tags: c#, list, linq

I need to prepare a chart wherein I'm required to show 3 lines. 
One for showing new issues for a week, second for closed issues for a week and **third for total accumulative open issues from first week to last week.**

For this reason, I have prepared a query and was able to create 2 separate lists successfully - one list maintains the weekly count of new issues and second list maintains the weekly count of closed issues.

Here is the sample data for first list (one which maintains new issues) :

```
        [0]: { Week = {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
        [1]: { Week = {3/5/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
        [2]: { Week = {5/21/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 4 }
        [3]: { Week = {6/4/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 7 }
        [4]: { Week = {6/11/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 4 }
        [5]: { Week = {6/25/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 7 }
        [6]: { Week = {7/9/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 3 }
```

From the above data, I get the total count of open issues for a particular week.

**Note: For both these lists the Week values contain date which falls on Sunday.**
As I need the week to start on Monday while displaying data in the chart.

Similarly for sample data for second list (one which maintains closed issues) :

```
[0]: { Week = {12/13/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
[1]: { Week = {7/9/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 3 }
[2]: { Week = {6/18/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 2 }
[3]: { Week = {7/23/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 8 }
[4]: { Week = {10/1/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 6 }
[5]: { Week = {8/6/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 3 }
[6]: { Week = {9/17/2017 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 }
```

From the above data, I get total count of closed issues for a particular week.

Here's the code for these lists :

```
var openIssuesList = getDetails
  .Where(x => x.ChangedTo == "Open")
  .Select(x => new { Week = x.Date.AddDays(x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek).Date, Detail = x })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Week)
  .Select(x => new
  {
    Week = x.Key,
    Count = x.Count()
  }).ToList();


var closedIssuesList = getDetails
  .Where(x => x.ChangedTo == "Closed")
  .Select(x => new { Week = x.Date.AddDays(x.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 0 : 7 - (int)x.Date.DayOfWeek).Date, Detail = x })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Week)
  .Select(x => new
  {
    Week = x.Key,
    Count = x.Count()
  })
  .ToList();
```

As I mentioned earlier, I need to prepare a weekly line chart using the data obtained from these lists. 
Now the final piece that remains is to fill in the missing week values into both of these lists using a third list which I have prepared.

I have prepared a list say **datesList** which contains all the dates (which fall on Sunday) between a specified date range.

Here's the sample data for this list :

```
[0]: {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[1]: {6/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[2]: {6/28/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[3]: {7/5/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[4]: {7/12/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[5]: {7/19/2015 12:00:00 AM}
[6]: {7/26/2015 12:00:00 AM}
//And so on ....
```

Explanation :

1. I need to compare the week values present in **datesList** with the week values of openIssuesList.
2. If a week value from **datesList** is also present in openIssuesList then do not add/alter such list value.
3. If a week value form **datesList** is not present in openIssuesList, then add such week value in openIssuesList list with it's Count value set to the **count value of it's previous record**.
4. Repeat the same steps for closedIssuesList. (If this process can be done simultaneously avoiding repetation then please suggest)

So from the above provided sample data for 3 lists here's how the newly updated **openIssuesList** list should like : (showing only few records)

```
[0]: { Week = {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 } // Exisiting record hence no change for this record
[1]: { Week = {6/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 } // As this date was not existing initially it's been added with Count value set to 1 (previous count value i.e. count value of record [0] which is equal to 1)
[2]: { Week = {6/28/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 } // As this date was not existing initially it's been added with Count value set to 1 (previous count value)

//and so on....
```

The same logic applies for closedIssuesList.

So **datesList** is kind of 'Master List' and we need to compare the other lists with this list. If a week value present in **datesList**, is missing from other lists, then add this week value to those other lists with the **Count** value being set to the count value of the previous record from those lists.

---

**My progress so far on this solution :**

```
openIssuesList = openIssuesList
  .Concat(datesList.Where(date => !openIssuesList.Any(pair => pair.Week == date))
  .Select(date => new { Week = date, Count = 0 });
```

But it gives me the following output :

```
[0]: { Week = {6/14/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 1 } // Exisiting record hence no change for this record
[1]: { Week = {6/21/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 0 } // WRONG - Instead of 1 I'm getting 0
[2]: { Week = {6/28/2015 12:00:00 AM}, Count = 0 } // WRONG - Instead of 1 I'm getting 0
```

Basically for every non-existing/new record I'm getting 0 as the value instead of fetching the previous record's count value.
Just a bit of tweaking is required which I'm unable to correct out.

Kindly help on this one.

Comment: aren't you getting 0 because you have new {week = date, count = 0} ?

Comment: Can I make any modifications to my current progress to achieve the required result?

Answer (score 1):

```
var matchedDates = 
  from date in datesList
  let open = openList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Week == date.Week)
  let closed = closedList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Week == date.Week)
  select new {date, open = open?.Count ?? 0, closed = closed?.Count ?? 0 };

int countSoFar = 0;
var resultList = openList.Take(0).ToList();
foreach(var matchedDate in matchedDates)
{
  countSoFar += matchedDate.open - matchedDate.closed;
  resultList.Add(new {Week = matchedDate.Week, Count = countSoFar});
}
```

This would be sped up by using a key-based datastructure that would allow easier seeking of matches instead of openList and closedList, such as ILookup from ToLookup.  That would look like:

```
Func<Detail, DateTime> toSunday = detail => {
  DateTime date = detail.Date;
  return date.AddDays(-1 * date.DayOfWeek);
};

ILookup<DateTime, Detail> byWeek = getDetails.ToLookup(toSunday);

List<DateTime> sundays = ...

int countSoFar = 0;
Func<int, int, int> countObserver = (open, closed) => {
  countSoFar += open - closed;
  return countSoFar;
}

var results = 
  from sunday in sundays
  let open = byWeek[sunday].Count(detail => detail.ChangedTo == "Open")
  let closed = byWeek[sunday].Count(detail => detail.ChangedTo == "Closed")
  select new {date, open, closed, soFar = countObserver(open, closed)};
```

Comment: For your matchedDates solution, using count value from both the openIssuesList and closedIssuesList is incorrect as what I need is to compare values between openIssuesList  and datesList and update the openIssuesList  itself with missing values. Then repeat the same procedure for closedIssuesList .

Comment: But datesList doesn't have any values.

Comment: Actually datesList contains all the dates (which fall on Sunday) between a specified date range (as specified in the question's description)

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a different approach and ignore datesList.

```
var newList = openIssueList.Tolist();
for (int i = 0; i < openIssuesList.Count - 1); i++)
{
    //add mising dates
    var nextModay= openIssuesList(i).Week.AddDays(7);
    while (nextModay < openIssuesList(i+1).Week)
    {
        newList.Add(new {Week = nextModay, Count = openIssuesList(i).Count);
        nextModay= openIssuesList(i).Week.AddDays(7);
    }
}
```